# Unit Circle - Angles Reflected Across Axis

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry

Can someone please explain why an angle, such as that shown in the image for f(e_2), is negative sin(theta)? I remember hearing something about it being reflected about the axis, but my trigonometry is very rusty and I can't remember anything about this.

I can see that the hypotenuse is 1 and remember that sin(theta) = opposite/hypotenuse. However, I do not understand why, for f(e_2), the angle is negative sin(theta) = opposite, rather than the positive. Please explain this phenomenon and if possible, provide links to a document that explains this further.

[image]

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not true that *"the angle of $f(e_2)$ is $-\sin \theta$"*.  What is true, however, is that the **x-coordinate** of $f(e_2)$ is $-\sin \theta$.

To see that this is the case, we should note that to get to the point $f(e_2)$ from the point $(0,0)$, we should go to the **left** (the negative $x$-direction) a distance of $\sin \theta$, and **up** (the positive $y$-direction) a distance of $\cos \theta$.  It follows that the coordinates of $f(e_2)$ are $(-\sin \theta, \cos \theta)$.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? If I was trying to find x, I would find sin(theta) = opposite/hypotenuse. For f(e_2), we have sin(theta) = opposite/1, which is sin(theta) = opposite. How do we factor in the -1 into the calculation, apart from just visually seeing that the x is going in the negative direction; how is the numerical calculation giving us the -1 part?

Comment: When you say *"I was trying to find $x$"*, what exactly is the quantity $x$ supposed to be?

Comment: If you want to do everything in a purely numerical fashion, then you should take both angles to be angles from the positive $x$-axis.  So, instead of taking the sine of $\theta$, you should be taking the sine of $\theta + 90^{\circ}$; this will give you the negative sign you're looking for.

Comment: In other words, if a vector creates an angle of $\theta$ with the $y$-axis, it creates an angle of $\theta + 90^{\circ}$ with the $x$-axis.  If $0 < \theta < 90^{\circ}$ (as it is in the picture), then that vector must be in the $-x$ and $+y$ quadrant.

Comment: I see. So why are we using sin to describe the x coordinate in this case? I thought cos = x and y = sin?

Comment: Excuse me, you're right!  That should be $x = \cos(\theta + 90^{\circ})$, which will give you $-\sin (\theta)$ for any $\theta$. We should be taking the cosine of $\theta + 90^\circ$.

Comment: Similarly (for $\theta$ as in the picture), we have $y = \sin(\theta + 90^\circ) = \cos(\theta)$.  You can verify that this holds either geometrically (as in the picture) or using the formulas for $\sin(A + B)$ and $\cos(A + B)$.

Comment: I think I see now. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Formulas such as opposite/hypotenuse etc. which serve as definition of sine, etc... when you begin with trignometry can be a plague later on. We have to change the definitions (this is easy) and our minds (this is more difficult). The general definition of  $(\cos(\theta)),\sin(\theta))$ is : the coordinates of $M$ on unit circle such that angle $\hat{\text{AOM}}=\theta$ (where $A(1,0)$).